# Spring boot internalization using a path variable

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization

Is it possible to use different language using a path variable?

Something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/it/user/antonio // italian
http://localhost:8080/en/user/antonio // english
```

I checked some tutorial but all of them uses a query parameter, like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/antonio?lang=it // italian
http://localhost:8080/user/antonio?lang=en // english
```

Comment: Just create your own `LocaleResolver` instead of using the default ones.

Comment: I'm sorry Deinum, I'm not that good with Spring. How should I use the custom LocaleResolver? Should I read the path variable in every request and change the locale? Do I have to do it in every controller?